# Send RaabbitMQ / System metrics to InfluxDB

Tags: rabbitmq, metrics, influxdb

**Dependency Details:**

**InfluxDB version : v0.10.0**

I am working on various infrastructure metrics for example CPU and RabbitMQ metrics. These all servers are type of m3.large on AWS. I want to send all these metrics to [influxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/). I tried [python-diamond](https://github.com/python-diamond) for sending metrics to influxdb but **InfluxDBHandler is not supported for InfluxDB versions > 0.9**.

I am using **influxDB  v0.10.0**
and I want to send RabbitMQ Metrics to InfluxDB server.I can't revert version to latest one (That is a dependency).What should I do ?.

Answer (score 0):

If `python-diamond` doesn't support versions `>0.9`, I'd recommend that you use the [Graphite plugin in Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/outputs/graphite) which should support diamond output.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to send RabbitMQ metrics through Telegraf RabbitMQ plugin to influxDB 1.1. Is there any way to send those metrics to influxDB 0.10.2?

Comment: Why is it that you cant upgrade from 0.10.2 to 1.1.1?

Comment: Current influxDB 0.10.2 is in production and its getting different metrics from huge sources. I can't revert influxDB 0.10.2.